# How to export a Codepen to use in HTML for sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codepen

This is my code pen:

http://codepen.io/hollowgast/pen/XpYEvb `XpYEvb`

I have tried figuring out how to get the CSS to work within the HTML. However, whatever I try it just seems to be blank. 
When i export the file, the HTML shows, however the CSS section with the background colours etc does not show in the exported ZIP file.

I am new to codepen and trying to add CSS to my HTML file. Anyhelp will be really appreciated!

Comment: You are using LESS, you will need to first compile it and use the compiled version.

Comment: I have compiled it. And when i export as ZIP still the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to **Change View** menu there are options in there for **Direct Code Links** to your `.html`, `.css`, `.less` and `.js` files.

Here's your css:

```
.tcb-quote-carousel {
  background: #17171c;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.tcb-quote-carousel .quote {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.tcb-quote-carousel .carousel {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.tcb-quote-carousel .carousel .carousel-indicators > li {
  background-color: #141e2e;
  border: none;
}
.tcb-quote-carousel blockquote {
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.tcb-quote-carousel .profile-circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no LESS processor you can compile the code on codepen-side:
[image]

Comment: I have compiled the CSS. Do i just go ahead and export it like before?

Answer (score -3):

first make tag style and put css code like this

```
<style>input code here</style
```

after dar copy html code and save document

Comment: Pardon? Sorry I don't quite understand.